# How to open .apk with Elementary OS?

Tags: pantheon-files, pantheon, android

I need to open some file.apk, When I have used Windows I'd Bluestacks but on Linux doesn't run. How to can I open file.apk on Elementary OS without Wine/Bluestacks? My DE is pantheon.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Genymotion to start an android emulator. Once a Genymotion emulator is started, drag & drop your apk, it will be installed and started like in Bluestacks.

https://www.genymotion.com/thank-you-freemium/

Comment: Thanks! Can I use playstore with genymotion?

Comment: According to this site https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-install-google-services-on-genymotion/en you can do it :)

Answer (score 0):

The .apk extension is an android application package. If you want to run an android app on elementary OS (which is what you were doing on Windows, since Bluestacks is an android emulator), you should search for an android emulator such as [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using Shashlik ([shashlik.io](http://shashlik.io)). It is an Android simulator (not emulator) which lets you run Android apps (APKs).Their website has instructions on using it